When do you stop research or consider the sunken-cost fallacy
While currently pursuing my undergraduate degree in Computer Science degree, I have been doing research that has unresolved conclusions for more than a year and a half.
The research topic itself is still new in the field, so the research that is done is still pretty much untouched and filled with possibilities. Although my supervisor is pessimistic about it due to the requirement of such high processing power (by default), I learned that, after a year of searching, some study might have the solution I needed. I read lots of papers, I learned lots of things along the way, and enjoyed the process, but the result remain inconsistent and more hurdles that has even higher stake than before keep coming.
I might not be giving my all, and I might have problems with my time allocation since the first half of the research is done concurrently with work, but if I don't submit proper result in time; I should burn all the work that I have done for a year and a half.
When do you consider burning all your work and when do you consider to keep moving?

I do not understand, do you have to write a bachelor thesis and this work is a part of it? Have you already completed all other formal requirements?

@yarchik yes this is a bachelor thesis that is the final requirement for graduation that I have not completed. I kinda don't want to throw all the work I did but all the answers are wise enough to tell me sometimes things can be postponed for better time

You should always bear in mind that sunk costs are not a valid justification for continuing investment.  But neither are they, in themselves, a valid justification for discontinuing investment.

There are usually a third and a fourth option between "burning your work" and "continue moving":

Writing up or otherwise delivering what we have learned so far, and terminating this line of inquiry
Writing up or otherwise delivering what we have learned so far, and continuing this line of inquiry

Even if you feel like you have gone from dead end to dead end, you have almost certainly learned something. Depending on what you and others have done, you may today be the world's foremost expert on what approaches do not work for problem X. This is valuable knowledge, and absolutely worth bringing to other people's attention.
Yes, negative results can be harder to publish than positive ones. This just means that you may need to think harder about how to package them.
I emphasize above that you can either continue this line of inquiry or stop it. This is a conscious decision you should take after some thought. If it seems like there are still promising avenues to pursue, then it might be worthwhile to do so. (With the understanding that if they do not pan out, you can again write up what you learned.) This will again commit you to a significant investment in time and work. But at least you already know the basics of your problem.
Alternatively, if you do not see a promising way forward, you can reorient yourself elsewhere. (After writing up what you found so far.) In this case, you will need to find an alternative problem, and start understanding the basics and the existing literature on it, so it will take a while to get up to speed.
There is nothing wrong with putting one topic on hold for a while and returning to it a few months or years later.
This is absolutely something where your advisor should help you. They can help you determine which of your learnings so far are publishable, and how to package them. In addition, they can help you in the decision process as to whether to continue working on this problem, or to switch elsewhere. Ideally, they might have ideas about alternative problems that may not be too far away from what you have been doing, so that the necessary startup investment is not too big.

The sunk cost fallacy just means you should not blithely continue the same direction without careful thought to the quality and value of that direction, it doesn't mean throw everything away or raze and burn - there are no doubt many valuables and useful bits to salvage and proceed ahead and many in the audience would be interested to learn what as well.

Follow up questions: How do you actually measure the other path is better than this one. Like if both require same learning curves for example or have results you might not get from your datasets, etc.

(+1) In my experience, the very process of formally "writing up" a research project can bring significantly greater clarity whether it is worth continuing the effort or not, and it can even reveal new angles of attack. Not sure why this works so well. I hypothesize that the effort of structuring one's writing also brings order into one's internal thought processes (analogous to "rubber duck debugging", perhaps)

Re your follow-up questions: that absolutely depends on the problem(s) at hand, and this is where an advisor is really indispensable. They should have more knowledge of what problems are out there, what has already been tried, which are the papers to read or skim etc. And they should be able to at least give a qualitative prediction of what will likely happen one way or the other. Of course, in research nothing is ever guaranteed in advance.

@RedSean Talk to someone in the field who you can trust not to subvert your efforts.

If it's about number theory or data structures or something similar, I could probably tell you if it's worth pursuing, if you'd like to email me the details. Or you could just describe it in very general terms here. I mean, if you solved the halting problem, then no. But I don't think anybody here is going to steal your idea.

@JessFuckett well I don't mind if they steal the idea because I would want to know how to make transformers (Artificial Intelligence topic, not the electronics one) more efficient for image segmenting. That fifty-headed hydra, I am still wondering what choices I could do to them to make them eat and learn faster. One of the ways I found is to avoid ViT gulping everything in pieces wholly in RGB. Park., et al. said in "RGB no More: Minimally Decoded Transformers" by converting the RGB to YbCr and then make bitmap out of it will make it faster a bit. But in the end it's still 50 headed hydra.

@StephanKolassa My supervisor actually prefer the original CNN to do the job due to lack of computing power at hand. But CNN researches are deeply saturated, and I feel like Image Transformer are perfect to be embedded in CCTV system the research was ought to offer to. I was curious about Transformers, and thought that the system is perfect to implement it, so I do something for one and half years that leads to my question here. Maybe I should've listened to them beforehand but like you guys said, things I learned are not meaningless either way.

...[hours later] Well, I never thought I'd escape that rabbit hole! So you understand images by mapping groups of pixels into vectors in some abstract space, and it's the same way that  chatGPT maps  semantic tokens into meaning vectors. Jee-zuss. Good luck.

But why would you think that converting the RGB to YbCr would speed up the transform? Apparently you tried it and it didn't make any difference, right? Have  you considered that maybe it just doesn't work? I'm getting sucked into the rabbit hole again.

@JessFuckett It's just my first finding of people's effort in taming visual Transformers, and in a sense YbCr would reduce the data that the transformer reads, which of course speed up the data reading as expected, it's similar like that CNN research where instead of learning whole image, it took coordinate points/skeleton of it. From your perspective, can I use some memory-allocation or data-processing to make things faster? It would be hard in python of course, I'm just wondering.

@JessFuckett Exactly! Visual Transformers are just "what if these images can also be quantized like words?", hence the first paper for it are called "Image worth 16x16 words" I also found the same fascination like you did here, but things I found are just way too precious to not be explored. Maybe it's just not me that will find things about it today, maybe some people will find same way and succesfully did what I want to do

Hopefully supplementing the answer of Stephan Kolassa, consider the following.
You don't have to abandon the research in the long term, but it might be wise, with advice from faculty, to put it on hold for now and focus on the undergraduate degree and building relationships with faculty. That will also help you get into graduate school.
To do this, create a research "notebook" capturing what you have learned is true and where the dead ends are. You can return to it in the future when time constraints are less binding. One of the issues with undergraduate and masters level research is the short time frame in which to complete anything significant. True research (exploring the unknown) can't be done on schedule. You can, of course, write it up as the draft of a paper as Stephan Kolassa suggests.
You have probably developed insights into the specific problem area and possibly the field that contains it. A research notebook can capture these so they won't be lost when and if you return to that problem.
Note that in many places prior publications are not expected of incoming graduate (even doctoral) students. What you have and can discuss might be more than enough to get you started in doctoral studies, even without publication. Note also, that the publication process itself can take a lot of time after first submission.
But a research/project notebook is valuable for any researcher at any level. If you review it regularly and add to it as any ideas or insights occur you have a valuable tool for a career.

Follow up questions: How do you actually measure the other path is better than this one. Like if both require same learning curves for example or have results you might not get from your datasets, etc.
